# Plex Media Server for Mac with a Pansonic Viera TC-P50S30

Tags: macos, network, plex

I have a Panasonic Viera TC-P50S30 that is connected to my home network with a wired connection. I also have a MacBook Pro that is running Mac OS 10.9.1 and Plex Media Server 0.9.8.18 and connected to the network with a wireless connection. Despite the seemingly simple setup, when I go to the DLNA Server option on my TV, I get an error message that says "DLNA server not found".

Does anyone know what steps I can take to try and troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Are you running the firewall on your Mac? Are your wired and wireless networks using the same subnet?

Comment: @IanC. I am not running the firewall on my Mac. I believe my wired and wireless networks are using the same subnet. Does that essentially mean that the IP addresses of both are of the form 192.168.0.x? If so, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ancient but since I have a similar setup, I'll chime in. You need to be sure you have DLNA enabled and setup on Plex Media server under Advanced options-DLNA. If this is setup correctly your viera will pick it up. *Note you miss out on plex best features by running it this way but this will correct the issue [image: DLNA advanced options]

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the firewall turned off on the Mac.

Can your TV pick up anything else on the net?

Next, make sure that your router is broadcasting UDP packets. Some routers do not, they swallow UDP.

Now check that Plex Media Server is running right and listening for connections. At the command line:

```
sudo netstat | grep 'Plex'
```

That should give you a list of ports that it is using. They will include:

```
TCP 32400     (for access to the Plex Media Server)
UDP 1900      (for access to the Plex DLNA Server)
TCP/UDP 32469 (for access to the Plex DLNA Server)
UDP 5353      (for Bonjour)
```

So then you know that it is up and running.

Make sure both your TV and Mac are thinking they are on the same subnet and that the netmask is correct on both.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've responded to your multiple comments with numbered replies. 1. Firewall is turned off. 2. TV's Internet connection is working 3. How do I test that the router is broadcasting UDP packets? 4. When I enter that command, I get nothing back in Terminal. Just returns me to the command prompt. However, I have tested the Plex server on my iPad so I think it is running properly. Also I have checked that DLNA is turned in the Plex settings. 5. Both are on the same subnet and have the same netmask.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using DLNA but some [other means of streaming your movies](http://elinux.org/DLNA_Open_Source_Projects).

I have quite a bit of experience trying to set up DLNA with a media server and our SONY Bravia.

The TV had no issues connecting to our physical media server via wifi or the internet, I just could not get DLNA to work. The ports were open etc. etc. I ended up even sniffing traffic but no go.

After about two weeks of trying to get it to work, I read enough about it being buggy that I gave up.

---

Having said that, it was over three years ago and back in Australia so the technology out there is probably a lot more mature by now.

Comment: I'm considering ordering a Roku because it doesn't seem the technology is much better.